# Axios Post Request against express server succeeds with images, fails with .mp4 files

Tags: express, axios

I have an axios post request to my express server that looks like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.state.file[0]);
const transport = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });

transport
      .post(DomainInfo.baseUrl + path, body, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        timeout: 0
      })
      .then(res => {
        resolve(res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        handleError(reject, error);
      });
```

When I post an image it succeeds, but when I try to post a video (.mp4) I get the error: 
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://staging.clubwealth.com/university/organization/contentFolder' from origin 'https://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
The amount of time it takes for this error to be thrown corresponds directly to the size of the .mp4 file.

My Express Server

```
var app = express();
var corsBaseOptions = {
  origin: 'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsBaseOptions));
app.use(session({...  }
}))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
var port = myArgs[0];
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
  console.log("listening on port ", port);
})
server.setTimeout(50000000000);
module.exports = app;
```

I'm pretty dang stumped. It would be amazing if you guys could help point me in the right direction here.
THanks!
I've tried stripping my post route down to just responding with res.status(200).send('ok') and still get the same result, so I figure it must be some kind of axios problem or express config problem. Don't hesitate to tell me i'm flat out wrong though! XD

Comment: Your request is failing due to CORS policy, this is when you request an api that has a different domain as your client. It might be that the CORS settings of the server that you try to connect to doesn't allow sending .mp4 from other domain. You can avoid this by either adding a proxy to your request or by creating your own api on server-side (and calling this api from client side).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have control over the server, but can't seem to find anything with CORS config that would specifically block .mp4 files in the form body.

Comment: A post request with a png looks like this: [https://i.imgur.com/rrOM55e.png] and a post request with a video looks like this: [https://i.imgur.com/aHpmN2q.png]. Is there something in CORS to do with specific file types, and is .mp4 blocked by default, or maybe CORS disallows files over a specific size/length?

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. I neglected the most important detail here, which my express server is set with nginx as a reverse proxy.

Nginx has a default maximum request size of 1M, which is why the videos weren't working.
When the size is too large Nginx responds with  413, which browsers do not properly display, which is perhaps why I was getting a CORS error.

If anyone runs into a similar problem, on ubuntu I went to etc/nginx/ngninx.conf and added the line `client_max_body_size 20M;` under http. If anyone else has additional insight as to why I was getting a CORS error with 403 file to large that would be great!

Thanks!